# Keycloak login with API

Tags: javascript, keycloak

i have a html page with javascript where i want to auto-login the user. I have the following code:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token";

const response = await fetch(url, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "client_id":"myclientid",
        "username":"admin",
        "password":"123",
        "grant_type":"password"
    }),
    headers:{
        //"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

On the keycloak server i added **Web Origins '*'**. I get the following error :

> POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token 400 (Bad Request)

I dont know why it is not working. When i use the terminal it works fine:

```
curl -i -d "client_id=myclientid" -d "username=admin" -d "password=123" -d "grant_type=password" http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/Myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

(keycloak version 4.8.3)

---

### Update

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: 'client_id=myclientid&password=123&username=admin&grant_type=password',
    headers:{
        "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
})
```

and i get the following response:

[image: response]

Comment: Is that supposed to say `curl` in your terminal example? If so, `-d` sends application/x-www-form-urlencoded, not JSON. Does your API accept JSON input …?

Comment: i tried both and same result ([here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.html) is where i got the example from) ... yes it should be curl (i edited the question)

Comment: ok when i use 'client_id=myclientid&password=123&username=admin&grant_type=password' as a body and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' it works but i get type 'cors' as a response and no access token like with curl

Comment: You mean you get a CORS _error_? If you are not making this call _from_ `http://localhost:8180/`, then of course you need to enable CORS. (_If_ this endpoint is supposed to be called from the client side to begin with - if you have to actually put credentials into client-side code(?), then probably rather not.)

Comment: @04FS i have an ionic app where i store the credentials and i want to auto login the user (this is because the credentials are also used at another point in the app). The code above is from `localhost:8080` and the keycloak server is `localhost:8580`.

Comment: And what is `localhost:8180` then? This is where you are sending the request to, so whatever is behind `localhost:8180` must allow this, by returning the necessary CORS headers.

Comment: sorry `localhost:8180` is the keycloac server. By entering Web Origins '*' on keycloak it should do so

Comment: So what is the exact error message?

Comment: i dont get one. In the question update you see the response but there is no access token. When i use the `curl` command i do get the token

Comment: Are you sure `mode: 'no-cors'` is the correct thing to use here in this scenario?

Comment: no i just tried different things. I have not much experience with cors issues. In the update i removed it so currently im not using `no-cors` mode.

Comment: Well then the two requests are maybe not a 100% identical … I’d try and debug that first, by setting up a script of your own, that logs the received headers and POST parameters to a file - and then call it once using your cURL request, and once from your JS code … and then see if there are any differences. (You might want to address that script via `localhost:8080`, so that you are not dealing with any additional CORS issues in this test scenario.)

Comment: @04FS found a solution. Thx for your comments they where helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its now working. The problem was sending JSON and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and also getting a ReadableStream instead of an string as a response. So here is my code now:

```
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: "client_id=myclientid&password=123&username=admin&grant_type=password",
        headers:{
            "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      });
    response.body.getReader().read().then(function (data){
        var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data.value);
        console.log(string);
    });
```

Comment: `const s = await response.text();` [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)]